# Renaming original migration file in Rails after doing the rename_table_migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, migration, rake

I happened to create a Query model in Rails and recently found out that this is one of the reserved words now..

I renamed the table using a new migration file and renamed all the files that were created (name of new model - Plot)

Question: is it OK to rename the original migration file (20111228212521_create_queries.rb) to 20111228212521_create_plots.rb)

and everything inside the old file:

```
class CreateQueries < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
   create_table :queries do |t|
    t.string :name
    t.text :content

    t.timestamps
    end
   end
 end
```

to

```
class CreatePlots < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
    create_table :plots do |t|
    t.string :name
    t.text :content

    t.timestamps
    end
   end
 end
```

??

I just don't want too many migration files and also worried that there may be some errors when I switch to production..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can change the migration file name, but you have to perform a few steps:

1. rake db:rollback to the point that queries table is rolled back.
2. Now change the name of migration file, also the contents.
3. Change the name of any Model that may use the table.
4. rake db:migrate

Comment: rolling back also means you remove all the data til your last rollback  version. This will work for development but if you in a production db, this is not advisable.

Comment: Even in development, I would need to throw away a lot of work done since I created that migration.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is to just make another migration file.

Migration files are meant to keep track of each and every change to the database. So, you're encouraged to make small one-off changes in a separate file. I can't speak for your situation, but in my situation, when I make a mistake like this, I simply create a new migration file and don't check the old migration file into source control. This way the errant changes are only on my local db and don't get into prod/dev/staging.

Comment: I don't understand the answer. create another migration file BUT with a NEW name? I have the same problem and would like to name it the same.

Answer (score 1):

*Aside* from rolling back, and especially useful for when you need to rename a migration from early on in production you can now in **Rails 4** create a new migration to rename it.

1. $`rails generate migration RenamesFooBarr`

and then in the method of the new migration add

```
rename_table :old_migration_name, :new_migration name
```

like this:

```
class RenamesFooBar < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
       rename_table :old_foo_bar_name, :new_foo_bar_name
   end
end
```

This will effectively take care of all the indexes as well in the up and down since ActiveRecord recognizes the *rename_table*

source:  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html

Comment: I am on rails 5.2 and `rails generate...` is not an option

Answer (score 0):

Simply, do like this

1. Rollback the migration for that queries. i.e `rake db:rollback`
2. Change migration file, class name and the content of it.
3. Finally, Migrate the database. i.e `rake db:migrate`